# Constraining Child Record Based on Parent Record

Tags: sql, database-design

In a timesheets data model, suppose I have the following parent table:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeInRole (
    employeeInRoleId PRIMARY KEY,
    employeeId,
    roleId,
    rate,
    effectiveFrom DATE, --from when can this employee assume this role
    effectiveTo DATE
);
```

and the following child table:

```
CREATE TABLE TimesheetEntry (
    startTime DATETIME,
    endTime DATETIME,
    employeeInRoleId,
    CONSTRAINT fk FOREIGN KEY (employeeInRoleId) REFERENCES EmployeeInRole (employeeInRoleId)
);
```

When I insert into `TimesheetEntry`, I'd like to make sure that time period falls within the boundaries of the parent record's `effectiveFrom/To`.

Is it possible to build this constraint into the DDL without use of a trigger, or do I have to maintain this constraint via a trigger or at the application level?

Answer (score 4):

(Here is some info about Oracle only)

It's not possible in Oracle with clear DDL but you can do something like this:

```
create table t1 (id number primary key, date_from date, date_to date);
create table t2 (id number primary key, date_from date, date_to date, parent_id number references t1(id));
create view v as 
select t2.* from t2 
where exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = t2.parent_id 
  and t2.date_from between t1.date_from and t1.date_to
  and t2.date_to between t1.date_from and t1.date_to)
with check option constraint chk_v;

insert into t1 values (1, sysdate - 5, sysdate); -- OK
insert into v values (1, sysdate - 4, sysdate - 3, 1); -- OK
insert into v values (1, sysdate - 6, sysdate - 3, 1); -- ERROR (WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation)
```

V is updatable view created with CHECK OPTION

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to build this constraint into the DDL without use of a trigger,"

It is possible in some RDBMS systems, but it is not possible in SQL.